# .Repeat .AutoReverse not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, animatewithduration

I am using animations to transform a button when it is clicked, I was able to make the button bigger. However, I thought that by using .Repeat and .Autoreverse, the button would go back to its normal state. (scale 1.0) but that is not the case!  Maybe I misunderstood the tutorials and questions that I read regarding `.AnimateWithDuration`   ??

This is the code that I am using:

```
 let button = sender as! UIButton

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.6,
        options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse, .AllowUserInteraction],
        animations:{
        button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2)
        }, completion: nil)
```

In another question I saw that the problem may be resolved by adding .AllowUserInteraction but that is not the case.

I don't know if it even matters but this code is enclosed within a touch event.

```
 @IBAction func addButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {}
```

What could be going on here? isn't this how you are supposed to reverse the animation?

Comment: With the .Repeat and .Autoreverse the button will be "pulsing". 
The code works as expected here in a test code.
    @IBAction func pushButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        
        let btt = sender as! UIButton
        
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.6,
            options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse, .AllowUserInteraction],
            animations:{
                btt.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2)
            }, completion: nil)
    }

Comment: Double check if the button is linked to this function, use a breakpoint to make sure its calling it.

Comment: @UlyssesR it is calling because the button does get bigger when I click it but it does not go back to its normal state

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the end of the animation you should reset the size of the object.
The `.autoreverse` just "reverse visually", but does not change the actual object size.

Try this out.

```
@IBAction func prss(sender: AnyObject) {
    let btt = sender as! UIButton

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.6, options: [.autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction], animations:{
        btt.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 5.0, y: 5.0)
    }, completion: { (finished) in
        btt.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    })
}
```

Comment: You're correct. I had to reset the button by using the completion. Thank you!

Comment: "The .Autoreverse just "reverse visually", but does not change the actual object size.". That helped me with my animate issue. Thx!